# App crashes when remote js debugging is turned on

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When remote js debugging is turned on my app crashes and close immediately with note "Unfortunately APP has stopped". To note, the app works perfectly when debugging is switched off. I had tried to change RN and React version to prev or next versions, but no success.

Please help to solve he problem. Thanks

Comment: Which RN version that you currently use? Where this crashes happened? On android or iOS?

Comment: Solved... Just should add the following code into android/app/build.gradle :compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.0") {
        force = true;
    }

Comment: I tried adding that to build.gradle, but then i couldnt build the project. It started throwing an error about `Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.`